# get first result from join

Tags: sql

Hi I have two separate queries that I want to join but only get the first result of the name:

| feature root | count | feature name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AD_LINEITEM | 340 | AdLineItem__test_name |
| ROBUSTA_INSTALOG | 96 | RobustaInstaLog*__test_name* |

1st query just gets the total count for each feature root:

```
select feature_root, count(*) as count
from feature
group by feature_root
```

[image]
2nd query gets a list of feature names for feature root:

```
select feature_root, feature_name
from feature
```

[image]

I am not sure how to join them because I want to keep the first table the same, but just add a column to get one feature name for that root. Thank you!

Comment: Add the DB engine you use for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> just add a column to get one feature name for that root

You don't seem to care which. So, just use the minimum or maximum?

```
select feature_root, count(*) as total, max(feature_name) as one_feature_name
from feature
group by feature_root;
```

You haven't tagged your request with your DBMS. Some DBMS offer an aggregation function to get the statistical mode (the most often occurring value). Something like:

```
select feature_root, count(*) as total, stats_mode(feature_name) as typical_feature_name
from feature
group by feature_root;
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can use `count()` window function to get the count, but also keep the features:

```
select feature_root, feature_name, count(*) over (partition by feature_root) fcount
from feature
```

Optional ANSI/ISO SQL feature T611, Elementary OLAP operations. Supported by most modern dbms's.

If not available, you can do a *self join* where you `GROUP BY` in a *derived table* to get the count:

```
select f1.feature_root, f1.feature_name, f2.fcount
from feature f1
join (select feature_root, count(*) as fcount
      from feature
      group by feature_root) f2
  on f1.feature_root = f2.feature_root
```

Edit: This is perhaps not what asked for, I realize when reading @ThorstenKettner's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `feature_root` is matching, just use inline view

```sql
SELECT t1.feature_root, ...<other columns>
FROM 
    (SELECT feature_root, <more columns> from table1) t1 inner join 
    (SELECT feature_root, <more coumns> from table2) t2 on t1.feature_root = t2.feature_root 
ORDER BY feature_root
```

You need to post DB Engine you use. Depends on engine, to select 1st row you can do
either ROW_NUMBER, LIMIT(1), TOP(1), SKIP/TAKE etc.

Comment: Will raise an _ambiguous column_ exception. (You need to specify which feature_root column you select.) Or you can join `USING(feature_root)`, to get only one feature_root column.